# why the injected service in parent component does not pass to the child component while routing using route.navigate in angular

Tags: angular

I have 2 component, 1 parent component 1 child component,
like so

```
(parent component)
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  providers: [SimpleService]
})

(child component)
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child'
})
```

it runs fine when I use both of them in parent component html file

```
<p>parent component</p>
<app-child></app-child>
```

but when I bind `onNavigate(text)` with a button in parent component html file,
like so

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

onNavigate(text: string){
    this.router.navigate(['/child-component', text]);
}
```

It gives me error when I navigate to child component

It runs fine if I put `providers:[SimpleService]` in `app.module.ts` file, but I want to limit the service scope in certain parent component only

It also runs fine if I put `providers:[SimpleService]` in child component file
like so

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  providers:[SimpleService]
})
```

but is it mean i injected the dependency twice?

do i have a better way to do this? (using service from parent component without `providers:[]` in child component when routing)

Comment: if you use as provider in Component, you inject a "new instance" of the service. If you want to limit the scope you can inject in a **module** and this module declare the components (or use `@Injectable({ providedIn: MyModule, })`: https://angular.io/guide/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```